# Where and How is stored Graphical UML data in MagicDraw

Tags: uml, magic-draw

I would like to know where/how is stored Graphical UML Data in MagicDraw, I mean the elements of the different diagrams, their size in the diagram and their location regarding the diagram and the other elements.

Thanks.

Comment: This kind of information is usually kept more or less secret by companies. I analyzed Enterprise Architect and published those internals. So either you find someone with Google who did similar things with MagicDraw or you have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you unzip the mdzip file you'll see the XMI files that are used by Magicdraw to store the model content. The extension used is .mdxml.

The node containing the model information is

```xml
<uml:Model ...>
```

the node containing the diagrams is

```xml
<mdOwnedDiagrams>
```

Here is an example of the Magicdraw Class Diagram representation as of Magicdraw 16:

```xml
<mdElement elementClass='Diagram' xmi:id='_14_0_15600de_1212923424656_220623_234' name='AF2000_AK006' visibility='public' ownerOfDiagram='eee_1045467100313_135436_1'>
    <mdElement elementClass='DiagramPresentationElement' xmi:id='_14_0_15600de_1212923424656_967717_235'>
        <elementID xmi:idref='_14_0_15600de_1212923424656_220623_234'/>
            <properties>
                <mdElement elementClass='ChoiceProperty'>
                <propertyID>LINE_JUMP_PLACE</propertyID>
                        <propertyDescriptionID>LINE_JUMP_PLACE_DESCRIPTION</propertyDescriptionID>
                <value>LINE_JUMP_PLACE_NONE</value>
                <choice xmi:value='LINE_JUMP_PLACE_NONE^LINE_JUMP_PLACE_HORIZONTAL^LINE_JUMP_PLACE_VERTICAL'/>
                <index xmi:value='0'/>
                </mdElement>
            </properties>
            <type>Class Diagram</type>
            <umlType>Class Diagram</umlType>
            <zoomFactor xmi:value='1.0'/>
            <diagramOpened xmi:value='true'/>
            <diagramFrameInitialSizeSet xmi:value='true'/>
            <diagramWindowBounds>3, 23, 1479, 836</diagramWindowBounds>
            <diagramScrollPositionX xmi:value='0'/>
            <diagramScrollPositionY xmi:value='0'/>
            <maximized xmi:value='false'/>
            <active xmi:value='true'/>
            <mdOwnedViews>
                <mdElement elementClass='DiagramFrame' xmi:id='_14_0_15600de_1212923424687_285936_247'>
                    <elementID xmi:idref='_14_0_15600de_1212923424656_220623_234'/>
                    <geometry>5, 5, 1078, 877</geometry>
                </mdElement>
                <mdElement elementClass='Class' xmi:id='_14_0_15600de_1213185089343_632469_293'>
                  <elementID xmi:idref='_14_0_15600de_1213135920046_452495_263'/>
                  <geometry>56, 84, 120, 54</geometry>
                </mdElement>
            </mdOwnedViews>
        </mdElement>
    </mdElement>
```